# Angular 1.5 recursively nested component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I'm looking to build something like an expand collapse using Angular 1.5 Components. The idea is that you could have one or more of these in a row, or you could nest them to create a tree. So, valid html might look like:

```
<expand-collapse title="This is my title">
    <p>This is my content</p>
</expand-collapse>
```

Or

```
<expand-collapse title="Level 1 Title">
    <expand-collapse title="Level 2 Title">
        <p>This is my content</p>
    </expand-collapse>
</expand-collapse>
```

So, my question is whether or not I can do this with an **Angular 1.5 Component** (not Directive) in a way that the Level 2 expand-collapse could be aware of it's parent expand-collapse. Typically when you nest components like this I think you would have something like:

```
component('expandCollapse', {
    ...
    require : {
        parentCtrl : "^expandCollapse"
    }
    ...
```

However A) nesting isn't REQUIRED in this case, and B) parentCtrl ends up being a never-ending recursive reference to the current $ctrl.

Is this something that can be done with Components? Or has it been explicitly banned for some reason?

Comment: May be you are looking for a directive with transclude option?

Comment: Well, I specifically would like to do it with a component, not a directive. I'm using transclude, but that doesn't solve referencing the way I would like it to.

Answer (score 0):

I see only two way :

- Define a directive for each level requiring the precendent level, this may lead to unnecessary code.
- Search use angular functions : `element.parent().controller('expand-collapse');`. This approach is usually not recommended but I don't see anything simpler /cleaner than this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
#1 would limit me to X layers, which I want to avoid at all costs. 
#2 is about all I've come up with so far myself, but I'm hoping there's something cleaner.

Comment: @LoganBlack UI ergonomy rules would dictate that probably in something like 5 or even 3 layers, you're doing it wrong aniway.

Comment: True, but still not a limit I want to impose.